Sharing focus state while still allowing them to bypass
iPhone 14, iOS v17.5.1
I've setup work focus and bedtime DND. I want a few other iOS users to see that I have a focus set in iMessage (eg.  Nick has notifications silenced), while still allowing those messages to bypass the focus and notify me (haptic when on silent, ringtone when not). My phone is pretty much always set to silent.
I see two options:

The "Allow Notifications" list for each focus
A contact's "emergency bypass" setting for texting/calling.

Problems with these:
Once I add a contact to the allow list on the focus, they don't appear to see that I have a focus set at all. They don't see the "has notifications silenced" message.
If, instead, I add the contact as an emergency bypass, they do see my focus status, but it plays the text/ring tone when in silent. This is annoying. I could set a custom silent ringtone for them but when not on silent I'd want it to ring.
So, unless I've missed something it doesn't look like I can have someone aware of my focus but also receive their notifications in the way I want while in that focus.
